# ImageView will not update when touched. "res cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

```
    playButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            switch(arg1.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    playButton.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.play_pushed));
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                {
                    playButton.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

The two res keywords are underlined in red. Simply trying to change the image to a darker version of itself when it is touched. All necessary images are located in the res folder. Any idea what the problem is?

UPDATE:
Updated the code a little and now it works perfectly:

```
    playButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            switch(arg1.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    playButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_pushed));
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    playButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changeing them to

```
getResources().getDrawable(...)
```

Since you are inside of a listener you may need `ActivityName.this.getResources().getDrawable()`

```
playButton.setImageBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_pushed));
```

`res` is the folder name but it isn't a variable that you have declared so the system doesn't know what it is.

[getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29)

Comment: Updated the post and found the solution.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change to `setImageDrawable`, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Better define your button with selectors in resources. Use code like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/green_large_btn_pressed" />
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/green_large_btn_pressed" />
<item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/green_large_btn" />
<item 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/green_large_btn" />
```

More info about button custom styles in [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style)

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView IV= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
IV.setImageResource(resID);
```

This will work I promise ;)